# Home page with or without slides

Tags: optimization, responsive-design, owl-carousel

I am making a static website for a friend of mine and the page load time is very crucial for the project since the Internet speed is rather slower in rural areas(near mountains, forests). My question is Does making home page with carousel slides slow down page load time comparing to a page without slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Obviously as you are increasing the loading of content but can be fast if you are cdn(content delivery network) such as cloudinay using the static color and css effects as many of the site are doing to load their content